# Navigation for app with multiple modules using single NavHostFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-module

I have an app with multiple feature modules that I want to navigate using a single NavHostFragment in my main module.

```
         app
       |  |  |
feature1  |  feature2
       |  |  |
       common
```

The nav graph seems to work fine (I can add all the Fragments from the feature modules and the startFragment shows up when I start the app) but sometimes I have to start a navigation from inside the feature modules but I dont have access to the NavHostFragment there.

for example :

```
findNavController(navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.loginFragment)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [findNavController() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment.html#findNavController(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)):

> This method will locate the NavController associated with this Fragment, looking first for a NavHostFragment along the given Fragment's parent chain.

This means that you don't need to pass in the `NavHostFragment` itself, but can pass in any Fragment created by your `NavHostFragment` and it'll correctly find the `NavController`.

Therefore in almost all cases, you should be passing `this` into `findNavController()`:

```
// From anywhere in one of the Fragments in your navigation graph
findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.loginFragment)
```